# microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package x64, error 1935

Tags: openoffice, windows-10-preview

I am working on Alienware 17, OS Windows 10 preview.
 When I try to install [Open office](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/?source=typ_redirect) it in turn tries to Install `Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable package x64` which then gives me following error.
[image]

I get same error if I try [downloading and installing package directly from Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=2092) directly.
I have already have installed `Microsoft visual c++ 2010 redistributable package x64` and it went fine.

**EDIT1:**
Found some extra info in Event Log

General:

```
Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 -- Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x800736FD. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, component: {03329364-ED3E-3EF1-ACB0-C1E9F5282929}
```

Detail:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MsiInstaller" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">11935</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-10-19T12:40:02.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1027</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>WIN-A46VO5QU58T</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2352286874-2299599541-1968600816-1000" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161 -- Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x800736FD. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, component: {03329364-ED3E-3EF1-ACB0-C1E9F5282929}</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data>(NULL)</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Binary>7B39424535313845362D454343362D333541392D383845342D3837373535433037323030467D</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**EDIT2 :** To @magicandre1981's comment
Fix it gives following error:
[image]

**Has anyone ran into similar problem and knows whats going on?**

Comment: @Ramhound where could I find it?

Comment: @Ramhound couldn't find anything searching `Error 19..` but found some info in event log hope this helps.

Comment: check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970652/en-us

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I will check in a couple of hours and will let you know the result, but so far it looks promising.

Comment: @magicandre1981 didn't fly - gives error, updated question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ask this in the Win 10 forums of Microsoft at answers.microsoft.com or social.technet.microsoft.com

Comment: There is a new Win10 Build available (Build 9860). Look if the Runtime works with this build.

Comment: I have the same error installing OpenOffice on Windows 8.1 32-bit. More specifically, access to C:\Windows\WinSxS\InstallTemp is denied. Do you have access to this folder?

Comment: Also, this is a matter of preference, but I like to use the all-in-one's (like [this one](https://github.com/abbodi1406/vcredist) so I won't have to worry about it going forward.  You can also install them through `winget` or `choco` via powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, [the following solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/transaction-support-within-the-specified-resource/fba64f34-4c16-4551-82d7-f22169be0d97?tab=AllReplies#tabs) (see quotation below) worked, when I couldn't install the 2008 package (2010 had installed without any problem) on Windows 10. I had tried everything else I could find on the Internet, like changing permissions on the WinSXS folder, but nothing worked.

I looked into my Windows CBS log file and found an error that was logged when the install of the 2008 package failed. It said `Error STATUS_RM_NOT_ACTIVE`, so I Googled that and arrived at a page that explained it meant *"transaction support within the specified resource manager is not started or was shut down due to an error"*. When I Googled *that*, I found the aforementioned page.

> This issue occurs if the Windows file system transaction log is corrupted. The Windows file system uses the transaction log to recover system transactions when a file error occurs.
>
> To fix this problem, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, type `cmd` in the Start Search box, and then *right-click* **cmd** in the Programs list.
> 2. Click **Run as administrator**, and then click **Continue**. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
> 3. At a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>    `fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\`
>
> Note: These steps assume that Windows is installed in the default location, on drive C. If this is not the case, adjust the drive letter of the folder path to match your configuration.
>
> 4. **Restart** the computer

Don't forget to restart!